# How move column to right of document in container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to move green box to right on body in container. Here's picture with what I want to achieve.

[image]

(Yellow is body). And here is what I've got

[image]

My code:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 680px;
  background: yellow;
}

.container {
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.col {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
  height: 200px;
}

.col-left {
  background: red;
  width: 27%;
}

.col-right {
  background: green;
  width: 64%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col col-left"></div>
    <div class="col col-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zdL2122h/

I can use jQuery to get right margin and move green box to the left of container. But I want to do it using CSS. How can I achieve it?

Update:
Here is what I've got:
I want to move image to the right, text and image are in columns and in container same as header (it's in container). I need to text be aligned with header and image doesn't have space on the right. So when I change screen size text still be aligned. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i understand your problem.

Here is a suggestion:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0
}

.img-leak {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.img-leak-content {
  width: 50%;
}

.img-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
}


/* Extra CSS */

header {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.img-leak {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.img-container {
  background: blue;
}

.img-leak-content {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
</header>
<section class="img-leak">
  <div class="img-container">your image here as background</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="img-leak-content">
      <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

What i did is positioning the image as absolute on the right of the section (50%).

Then, i wrap the content on an div with 50% width, inside the container.

This way, the text will not enter on the image area and the image will not enter on the text too.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Flexbox!  You can easily define an order for the columns

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 680px; 
  background:yellow;
}
.container {
  display: flex; /* <--- This turns it into a flexbox container */
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
}
.col {
  margin: 0 10px;
  height: 200px;
}
.col-one {
  background:red;
  width: 27%;
  order: 1; /* <--- This changes the order */
}
.col-two {
  background: green;
  width: 64%;
  order: 0; /* <--- This changes the order */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col col-one"></div>
    <div class="col col-two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your question right but I figured something like this

```
<div class="bod">
  <div class="green"></div>
   <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/usym878a/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
.wrapper{
width: 680px; 
height: 200px;
background:yellow;
margin : 0;  
padding : 0;
}
.container {
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
  padding : 0;
}
.col {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
}

.col-left {
  background:red;
  width: 130px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.col-right {
  background: green;
  width: 330px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col col-left"></div>
    <div class="col col-right"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have wasted my time to fix your problem and now you updated the question, honestly this is not the way. You should know how to ask a question on this platform.